# Multiple counts from multiple tables in a single query - EF Core, LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've supplied a simplified version of the problem I'm tackling, essentially, I want to run a count across multiple entities that inherit the same interface in a single query, the example I've given is my current working solution however it's not very performant in production when dealing with 20+ entities as each count executes a single query. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can use LINQ Query Syntax to improve on my current solution?

```
public class EntitySummary {
     public EntityType EntityType { get; set; }
     public int Count { get; set; }
} 

public enum EntityType
{
   Entity1,
   Entity2,
   Entity3
}

public interface IDateModified {
     public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
}

public class Entity1 : IDateModified {
     public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2 : IDateModified {
     public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
}

public class Entity3 : IDateModified {
     public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
}

public void Summary(){

  var summary = new List<EntitySummary>{
      new EntitySummary {
       EntityType = EntityType.Entity1,
       Count = Context.Entity1.Count(x => x.DateModified < DateTime.Now)
      },
      new EntitySummary {
       EntityType = EntityType.Entity2,
       Count = Context.Entity2.Count(x => x.DateModified < DateTime.Now)
      },
      new EntitySummary {
       EntityType = EntityType.Entity3,
       Count = Context.Entity3.Count(x => x.DateModified < DateTime.Now)
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you store those entities in your database? Is each one a separate table or are you using a single table with a [discriminator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance?view=aspnetcore-5.0#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration)? Unless you are using the latter, think about how you could solve this in SQL with a single question: You will notice that you cannot count entities in multiple tables individually in a single query.

Comment: Hi @poke, each one is a separate table :)

Comment: Are you sure it's separate execution that hits performance? It more likely that the time the queries themselves take far outweighs this effect.

Comment: I think this results in one database query, Use [Database.Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.log?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) to verify this in your debugger. For instance: `DbContext.Database.Log = (sqlText) => Debug.WriteLine(sqlText);`